# Laravel 5.6 How to take datas by id and print 10 by 10

Tags: mysql, laravel

I was printing 50 questions yea it was working as well. But requirement changed how to take questions by topic_id and print them by 10 by 10 in 5 pages. Good news. I took topic_id and questions. But how do i take from Database in Controller.

**My Database Column = Question**

```
| id | topic_id |question_text|
| ---|:--------:|:-----------:|
| 1  |     5    | question1   |
| 2  |     6    | question2   |
| 3  |     7    | question3   |
```

**topic_id => request of questions number**

```
array:9 [▼
"_token" => "N6AJGDf95iQ5WOae3WKibS3yiEdzXJmW7RPXu6sE"
1 => "5"
2 => "3"
3 => "5"
4 => "1"
5 => "3"
6 => "6"
7 => "7"
8 => "8"
]
```

**It was my old Controller**

```
$questions = $request->input('questions');
$inquiries = $request->input('inquiries');
$queries = $request->input('queries');
$examinations = $request->input('examinations');
$inquisitions = $request->input('inquisitions');

$except = [];

$questions = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$except = array_merge($except, $questions->pluck('id')->toArray());
$inquiries = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get(); 
$except = array_merge($except, $inquiries->pluck('id')->toArray())
$queries = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get();
$except = array_merge($except, $queries->pluck('id')->toArray());
$examinations = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get();
$except = array_merge($except, $examinations->pluck('id')->toArray());
$inquisitions = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get();

foreach ($questions as &$question) {
  $question->options = QuestionsOption::where('question_id', $question->id)->inRandomOrder()->get();
}
return view('exams.create', compact('questions','inquiries','queries','examinations','inquisitions'));
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="{{ route('exams.store') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div id="account_details">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Нэгдүгээр хэсэг
    </div>
    <?php //dd($questions) ?>
@if(count($questions) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($questions as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>

                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div><input type="button" value="Дараагын хуудас" onclick="show_next('account_details','user_details','bar1');">
</div>

<div id="user_details">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Хоёрдугаар хэсэг
    </div>
    <?php //dd($questions) ?>
    @if(count($inquiries) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($inquiries as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>

                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div>
<input type="button" value="Өмнөх хуудас" onclick="show_prev('account_details','bar1');">
<input type="button" value="Дараагын хуудас" onclick="show_next('user_details','qualification','bar2');">
</div>

<div id="qualification">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Гуравдугаар хэсэг
    </div>
    <?php //dd($questions) ?>
    @if(count($queries) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($queries as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>

                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Өмнөх хуудас" onclick="show_prev('user_details','bar1');">
    <input type="button" value="Дараагын хуудас" onclick="show_next('qualification','exort','bar2');">
</div>

<div id="exort">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Дөрөвдүгээр хэсэг
    </div>
    <?php //dd($questions) ?>
    @if(count($examinations) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($examinations as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>

                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div>

<input type="button" value="Өмнөх хуудас" onclick="show_prev('qualification','bar1');">
<input type="button" value="Дараагын хуудас" onclick="show_next('exort','wex','bar2');">

</div>

<div id="wex">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Тавдугаар хэсэг
    </div>
    <?php //dd($questions) ?>
    @if(count($inquisitions) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($inquisitions as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>

                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="torol" value="1">

<div class="form-group">
<input type="button" value="Өмнөх хуудас" onclick="show_prev('exort','bar1');">
<button type="submit">Дуусгах</button>
</div>

</div>

</form>
```

**ExamsController@create**

this is it. cause I need to take inputs requests of question arrays.

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>

                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$questions = Question::with(['options' => function($query) {
     $query->inRandomOrder();
}])->inRandomOrder()->paginate(10);
return view('exams.create', compact('questions'));
```

Bear in mind this solution takes for granted you have a eloquent `hasMany` relation between `question` and `questionOption` called `options`.

If you need more information about how to handle pagination in your view check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination).

**EDIT**

If you just need to slice in five groups your questions, you can just do it like this:

```
$questions = Question::with(['options' => function($query) {
     $query->inRandomOrder();
}])->inRandomOrder()->limit(50)->get()->slice(5);
return view('exams.create', compact('questions'));
```

To display the results in your view you could do something like this:

```
@foreach($questions as $group) 
    @foreach ($group as $question) 
        {{$question}} 
        @foreach($question->options as $option) 
            {{$option}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sir please Take a look my updated question. that's why i am separating 5 parts. and printing em 5 separated `foreach` s. i know how to use pagination _i hope so_ .

Comment: @RukaXing I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding the view, I don't know cyrillic/mongolian, but for what I can read there are 5 different categories?

Comment: Yes. 5 different views. i must separate 5. that's why i used to use `$questions = $request->input('questions');
$inquiries = $request->input('inquiries');
$queries = $request->input('queries');
$examinations = $request->input('examinations');
$inquisitions = $request->input('inquisitions');`

Comment: @RukaXing so they go in the same view, but in different blocks? If that's the case you wouldn't need pagination nor separated queries. But I don't get why you get the `request` input, I can't see you using it anywhere in your code.

Comment: yes yes absolutely. need separated query sir. i guess. sorry for my English sir. I think i didn't explain as good.

Comment: @RukaXing Okey, let's break it down, why do you need `$request->input('questions')`?

Comment: Okay i updated my question again. I need that cause i need take inputs request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167797/discussion-between-asur-and-ruka-xing).